# Manage Transfers via Outlook Calendar

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js

I am trying to automatize that:
When a person need to ask for a Transfer, it sends a mail and, depending on if it get accepted or not, the transfer get added in the outlook calendar as event that the user that made the request can see.
I tought that probably the best way to do that is a mail with smth like that as body:

```
{
dear xx,
bla bla request
Start date: 22/2/2222
End date: 33/3/3333
Why?: Because im bored
}
```

When you drag the mail "onto the calendar" it automatically create an event, then i want to have a super simply button that u press and sets "Start and stop" date based on the body of the mail.
And also possibly add the person that made the request to who can see that event. Idk if I explained myself well but thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Ok. Lets define User 1 and 2.
User 1 will be the one that need this script and is in charge to accept Transfers(If its not clear, i mean like "My boss is transferring me to the new office in San Francisco.")
User 2 need to make the request(and be transfered if its accepted lmao) and shouldnt need a script or anything.

BUT User 2 need to make a Mail with a body like the one that i did above where its indicated STart/End date so the script its easy to be done.

User 1 should just press a button and, based on the email that User 2 sent, will automaticallly create an appointment in the User 1 calendar with the participation of User 2.

That because User 1 need ALWAYS to know who and when someone is in Transfer but User 2 need to know just when he's but not if User 3 is in Transfer.

Comment: It is not clear which Outlook Addins API you are trying to use. Can you please share code-snippet you are trying out?

Also, as your scenario involves approval process, you may also want to look at Actionable Messages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/

Comment: Also, are you trying this in Outlook Desktop, Outlook on Mac, Outlook on Web, Outlook on Android or iOS?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT actually im just trying a way to make this work, and since I havent exactly understood how those the Office scripts works im asking "Thats my problem, how do i solve it?"
Im atm trying in desktop, but i think that my boss(That asked me to do that) need it in web, i will ask if that change smth

Comment: Okay. Your use-case mentioned is not clear to us to help you further on this. If you could explain what is the use-case for user and what should addin provide in that use-case, it will help us help you.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Ok sorry i will try to explain better, i Edit my request in a few minutes

Comment: Here is what we understood: 
User1->Sends mail with request (specifies the date in email), 
User2->Approves the mail request, 
If approved, User1 & 2 both get calendar event created with the dates as specified in email. 
If our understanding is correct then, this doesn't look like an Add-in use case. You can use [actionable messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email#:~:text=%20Send%20an%20actionable%20message%20via%20email%20in,by%20using%20the%20Card%20Playground%2C%20which...%20More%20) instead of using simple mail with meeting details.

Comment: @outlookadd-insteam-msft ye but what if not everybody haves Office 365

Comment: Can you please specify what does 'not everybody haves Office 365' mean here? Are you talking about on-prem or any outlook rich client?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Web Add-ins work in the context of current item only. However, you may consider using EWS or Graph API for getting the job done. But a web add-in itself doesn't provide anything for that out of the box.

Comment: So in the case of the picture:https://imgur.com/a/NkwgaIt how do I change starting and end date based on the body of the text?